# Reported speech- Another Question

Tags: word-usage

What would be the reported speech for this *We met two weeks ago*? My interest is with the word *ago* and how to use it in reported speech.

Comment: I would exchange the word _before_ for _ago_.  " He said they had met 2 weeks before."

Comment: 'before' tends to raise the question 'before what? 'previously' might be better but it is a matter of taste.

Answer (score 2):

> They said they had met two weeks ago / [before](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/before) / [prior](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/prior) / [previously](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/previously) / [earlier](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/earlier)

The problem with using "ago" in this context is we don't know if it was two weeks before "now" (i.e. when the speech is being reported) or two weeks before they said it. The other options feel less ambiguous.